# Don't understand this AttributeError:'str' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, class, tkinter, attributes

I am making an application that will allow to display a running text in the window, but just started to parse the OOP, and I would like to know how to fix this error... There is also an example that works as needed, it will be shown below the script with an error.

```
class Main_Desktop():

    def __init__(self,parent,i,text):
        self.i=i
        self.parent=parent
        self.ticker=Text(parent,height=1,width=100)
        self.text=text
        self.ticker.pack()
        self.txt(i)

    def txt(self, i):
        i = 0
        self.text = ('' * 20) + self.text + ('' * 20)
        x = self.text[i:i + 20]
        self.ticker.insert("1.1", x)
        if i == len(self.text):
            i = 0
        else:
            i = i + 1
        self.ticker.after(100, lambda: Main_Desktop.txt(self.text[i:i + 20], i))
```

Here is an example and it works as needed:

```
root =Tk()
text="string"
text = (' '*20) + text + (' '*20)
ticker = Text(root, height=1, width=20)
ticker.pack()

i = 0
def command(x, i):
    ticker.insert("1.1", x)
    if i == len(text):i = 0
    else:i = i+1
    root.after(100, lambda:command(text[i:i+20], i))

command(text[i:i+20], i)
```

Comment: Which line generates this error?

Comment: What's the point to asking us about an error without any information about where it occurs (e.g. the `traceback`).  Sometimes we can fetch that information by running your code, but I doubt if your example copy-n-paste runnable.

Answer (score 4):

```
AttributeError:'str' object has no attribute 'text', tkinter
```

This means that somewhere in your code, you have a `str` object that you are trying to call the `.text()` method of it on.
Because your `str` object does not have a `.text()` method, you get that error.

To resolve this, check your variable types, you should not be using a `str` object, but rather an object that has `.text()` method

Comment: Thanks, it helped, but the application does not work as it should. Could you tell me why I get the result of displaying windows vertically, when the window should be one and the text in it should run:def __init__(self,parent,i=0):self.i=I self.parent=parent self.x=Main_Desktop.text[i:i+20] self.txt(self.x,i)
def txt(self,x,i=0):
    text='abc'
    text = (' '* 20) + text + (20*'')
    x = text[i:i+20]
    ticker=Text(root,height=1,width=20)
    ticker.pack()
    ticker.insert("1.1", x)
    if i == len(text):i = 0
    else:i = i + 1
    root.after(100, lambda: Main_Desktop.txt(x,i))

Comment: @PhilipVasilevski It is very difficult to read it like this, plus I don't necessarily have the expertise on tkinter. Perhaps you should open another question. If this post helped you solve your initial problem, please help mark it as the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
from tkinter import *


class Main_Desktop():

    def __init__(self, parent, i, text):
        self.parent = parent
        self.i = i
        self.text = text
        self.ticker = Text(parent, height=1, width=20)
        self.text = (' ' * 20) + self.text + (' ' * 20)
        self.ticker.pack()
        self.txt(self.text[i:i + 20], i)

    def txt(self, x, i):

        self.ticker.insert("1.1", x)
        if i == len(self.text):
            i = 0
        else:
            i = i + 1
        self.parent.after(100, lambda: self.txt(self.text[i:i + 20], i))

root = Tk()
i = 0
text ="string"
app = Main_Desktop(root, i, text)
root.mainloop()
```

This results as you want and is written as your code.